# list records that first column is blank in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table in database, This table have 2 columns, 1.name, 2.surname. Some of records in this table are blank. I want get and lists all records that name's column is blank.

I can find records by `@table = Table.find_by_name("string")`, but if column is blank, how can list empty records?

Comment: have you tried anything so far? start reading here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 1):

```
MyModel.where('name is null')
```

Please read the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) carefully.